# Prove that $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos (x+k/n)\pi=\frac{\sin n(x+1/2)\pi}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Prove that 
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos \left( x+\frac{k}{n} \right)\pi=
\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sin n\left( x+\frac{1}{2} \right)\pi $$

given that
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( x+\frac{k}{n} \right)\pi=
\frac{\sin n\pi x}{2^{n-1}}$$ and $$\sin \left( \phi+\frac{\pi}{2} \right)=
\cos \phi$$

From my understanding,

$$\frac{\sin n\left( x+\dfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi}{2^{n-1}}=
\frac{\sin n\pi x}{2^{n-1}}$$

Because $\sin \pi x$ has period $\dfrac{1}{2}$, I can say

$$\frac{\sin n\left( x+ \dfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi}{2^{n-1}}=
\frac{\sin n\pi x}{2^{n-1}}=
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( x+\frac{k}{n} \right)\pi$$

So I want to use the given $\sin \left( \phi+\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)=
\cos \phi$, but I can't prove that

$$\sin \left( x+\frac{k}{n} \right)\pi =
\sin \left( \phi +\frac{\pi}{2} \right),$$

specifically

$$\frac{k}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Perhaps I'm missing some tools for me to answer this problem.  How would you solve this problem? Is my logic flawed?

Comment: Set $x=y+\dfrac12$ in $$
\frac{\sin\pi n(x+1/2)}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{\sin\pi n(x)}{2^{n-1}}
$$

Comment: Can you give me more of an explanation? Here's what I'm doing. $$ Let \:x=y+1/2\:then\\ \frac{sin\pi n(x+1/2)}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{sin\pi n(y+1/2+1/2)}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{sin\pi n(y)}{2^{n-1}}\:then\\\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}sin\pi (y+k/n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}sin\pi (y)\:because\:periodity.\:Then\\let \:y=(\phi+\pi/2).\:Then\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}sin\pi (y)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}sin\pi(\phi+\pi/2)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}cos(\phi)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}cos(\phi+k/n) $$ Obviously, this is wrong. My final notation ends using phi as the independent variable instead of x. I feel like I'm doing something obviously wrong, and simple too.